# XAMPP PHP Named Arguments gives " syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'"

Tags: php, xampp, arguments, named

In an include file I declare a function

```
function patch_163_output_row_header(
    string $title,
    string $label,
    $help,
    bool $read_only=false,
    bool $required=false,
    string $label_cell
    )
```

and when I compile this using the XAMPP PHP compiler (8.1.6 as far as I can tell) it is OK
In another file I try to use the function

```
    patch_163_output_row_header(
        title:$title,
        label:$label,
        help:$help,
        read_only:$read_only,
        required:$required,
        label_cell:$label_cell
        );
```

when I try to compile I get the error mentioned above on the"title" line.

I can see no obvious issues - title does not seem to be a reserved word?

The strange thing then is that these two files are part of a website and when they are executed by the same XAMPP stack (presumably using the same PHP compiler?) there are no errors reported and they work.

Comment: I can see your syntax error, but the code executes: https://3v4l.org/7oTrM#v8.1.6 Can you make an executable example and confirm it doesn't execute because of the syntax error?

Comment: How do you get the PHP version info? Maybe there are many versions of PHP installed, and you are running the code with older version.

Comment: Thanks - I realise now I had 2 versions of XAMPP installed - the newer one ran the website (which worked), the older ws invoked by my development environment